# How to apply lead assignment rules for the lead submissions from the ZOHO forms

Tags: zoho

I have a ZOHO form embedded in a web page and it collects and sends its submissions to ZOHO CRM as leads. ZOHO CRM has been configured with a lead assignment rule. The issue is that the lead assignment rule doesn't apply to the leads generated by the ZOHO form. How I can configure to apply the lead assignment rule for ZOHO form submissions as well.

Answer (score 1):

The option is available inside the integrations tab of the particular form settings.

1. Go to **Forms** App of the ZOHO
2. Go to **Settings** of the particular form
3. Go to **Integrations** tab
4. Scroll down to the sections called **Actions**
5. Check true the **Assignment Rules** options (Follow the steps)
6. Click on the button **Integrate** to finish it

[image]